# Pyspark copy values from other columns depending on a specific column

Tags: pyspark

I want to create the New column depending on the column A values using Pyspark.
I want to take the Column B values for items greater than 1300 when creating the new column.
but I want to keep the Column C values for items less than 1300 when creating the new column.

I am only a beginner. Thank you for your help.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1210 | 100 | 200 | 200 |
| 1300 | 70 | 50 | 70 |
| 1200 | 10 | 50 | 50 |
| 1310 | 15 | 300 | 15 |

I have tried to filter out items greater than 1300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so with `col` and `when`. When A >= 1300 then take column B otherwise column C.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

data = [
    [1210,  100, 200],
    [1300,  70, 50],
    [1200,  10, 50],
    [1310,  15, 300]
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['A', 'B', 'C'])

df.withColumn('New', when(col('A') >= 1300, col('B')).otherwise(col('C'))).show()

+----+---+---+---+
|   A|  B|  C|New|
+----+---+---+---+
|1210|100|200|200|
|1300| 70| 50| 70|
|1200| 10| 50| 50|
|1310| 15|300| 15|
+----+---+---+---+
```